# How to access multipart/form-data form parameter in liferay action

Tags: file-upload, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I have a form which consist of a regular text input and a file upload.

```
<portlet:actionURL var='create' name="addProduct">
</portlet:actionURL>    
<form id="addform" action="<%=create%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>Product Name</dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="text"  name="name"  />
        </dd>
        <dt>Image File</dt>
        <dd>
            <input type="file" name="imgFile" >
        </dd>
    </dl>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

in the portlet Class I want to access file uploaded and parameter "name". I find out when I put enctype="multipart/form-data" in my form I can't get other(here the "name" parameter) by
*request.getParameter("name")* or *ParamUtil.getString(request,"name")*.

but when I remove enctype="multipart/form-data" I can see the "name" parameter, but of course the uploaded file is missed. how can I have both uploaded file and regular parameter

EDIT:
my action implementation is:

```
@ProcessAction(name = "addProduct")
public void addProduct(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
        String name = ParamUtil.getString(request,"name");
            String anotherTryForName = request.getParameter("name");
        System.out.println(name);
            System.out.println(anotherTryForName);
        System.out.println(uploadImg(request));
}
private String uploadImg(ActionRequest request) {

        String realPath = getPortletContext().getRealPath("/");
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {

            UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil
                    .getUploadPortletRequest(request);
            String sourceFileName = uploadRequest.getFileName("imgFile");
            File file = uploadRequest.getFile("imgFile");
            try {
                bytes = FileUtil.getBytes(file);
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            File newFile = null;

            if ((bytes != null) && (bytes.length > 0)) {

                try {
                    newFile = new File(realPath + "demo/productimg/"
                            + sourceFileName);
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                            newFile);
                    fileInputStream.read(bytes);
                    fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    fileInputStream.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("File Not Found.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return sourceFileName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception::::" + e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
}
```

Comment: There are plenty of hits for searching *liferay upload* on google, even containing code samples.

Comment: I'm not looking for liferay file upload sample. my file upload work correctly. my problem is when I use multipart form I can't access my regular parameters. I searched it and find nothing

Comment: ah I see, sorry. I'm giving my guess as an answer then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found that when the form is multipart/form-data  I should get extra parameter(like "name") from UploadPortletRequest instead of ActionRequest.

correct form of getting parameter:

```
UploadPortletRequest uploadRequest = PortalUtil
                    .getUploadPortletRequest(request);
String name = ParamUtil.getString(uploadRequest,"name");
```

Comment: Also not working for me. It seems we are forced to use another framework instead of liferay-mvcportlet

Answer (score 0):

As you post to a portlet action, parameters should be namespaced to the portlet. Try

```
 <input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>name"/>
 ...
 <input type="file" name="<portlet:namespace/>imgFile"/>
```

Alternatively you could use the aui taglib, e.g.

```
 <aui:form ...>
    <aui:input ... name="name"/>
 </aui:form>
```

This taglib automatically adds the namespace

Comment: ok, then we'll need to look at the action implementation that you use. Can you add the relevant parts of your action handler to your question?